# JavaScript - Sort 2D array, numerically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
function getCombinations(_list) {
    var fn = function(active, rest, a) {
        if (!active.length && !rest.length)
            return;
        if (!rest.length) {
            a.push(active);
        } else {
            fn(active.concat(rest[0]), rest.slice(1), a);
            fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    return fn([], _list, []);
}

var list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log(getCombinations(list));
```

Which returns a 2D array, filled with every combination ...

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
, [ 1, 2, 3 ]
, [ 1, 2, 4 ]
, [ 1, 2 ]
, [ 1, 3, 4 ]
, [ 1, 3 ]
, [ 1, 4 ]
, [ 1 ]
, [ 2, 3, 4 ]
, [ 2, 3 ]
, [ 2, 4 ]
, [ 2 ]
, [ 3, 4 ]
, [ 3 ]
, [ 4 ]
]
```

But I want the following order

```
[ [ 1 ]
, [ 1, 2 ]
, [ 1, 2, 3]
, [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
, [ 1, 2, 4]
, [ 1, 3 ]
, [ 1, 3, 4 ]
, [ 1, 4 ]
, [ 2 ]
, ...
, [ 4 ]
]
```

I tried using `.sort`, but that sorts the combinations alphabetically

```
getCombinations([ 1, 2, 10 ]).sort()
// [ [ 1 ]
// , [ 1, 10 ]
// , [ 1, 2 ]
// , [ 1, 2, 10 ]
// , [ 10 ]
// , [ 2 ]
// , [ 2, 10 ]
// ]
```

But this is not the ordering I want.

How can I sort the array, so that the contents of the array are treated numerically, and the result is the same order as I mentioned above?

Comment: Can I convince you to generate the combinations in the order you need them?

Comment: @user633183 I thought about that. It's been a while since I've played around with recursive programming, but I'll take a look at it. Whether in creation or afterwards in sorting, it's all the same.

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: @JaredSmith the JavaScript `sort()` method is functional programming

Comment: @Birrel 1. It's not, `Array.prototype.sort` [mutates the original array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and 2. even if it were you don't call it anywhere in the provided code. I could *maybe* see it qualifying because of your use of recursion. Maybe. Please read the tag description before using it on questions, I (and I assume others subscribing to the tag) don't want to get spammed with a bunch of emails not relevant to our interests.

Comment: @ftor you removed the tag that my answer depended on :3

Comment: @user633183 oh, this was not my intention. rollback if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a comparator function to `sort()` that implements your desired sorting logic.

```
arr.sort((one, other) => {
    let minL = Math.min(one.length, other.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < minL; i++) {
        if (one[i] != other[i]) return one[i] - other[i];
    }
    return one.length - other.length;
});
```

Comment: Simple, and the first to the finish line. Thanks for checking it and modifying your solution.

Comment: nice use of the `!=` type instead of `!==` to discard `undefined`s. And corrected quick enough that i didn't have time to comment ;)

Comment: @Birrel, Sorting the result is a backward way to approach the problem. I recommend you view Nina's answer that generates the combinations in the correct order.  This is especially important if you're generating combinations of a large input where sorting increases time cost exponentially for each element added to the input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use instead of sorting afterwards, a function which creates the wanted combinations as sorted result directly.

```js
function getCombinations(list) {

    function iter(index, values) {
        var temp = values.concat(list[index]);
        result.push(temp);
        if (++index < list.length) {
            iter(index, temp);
            iter(index, values);
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    result = getCombinations(list);

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is tagged with functional-programming so I thought I'd show a functional way to generate the combinations in the correct order.

By *functional*, I mean using using functions that oper­ate solely on their input argu­ments (rather than rely­ing on external state) and return a value (rather than rely­ing on muta­tion). This is a direct contrast to *imperative* style.

Using `Array.prototype.sort` is neither necessary nor functional (it mutates its input), and so it will not be used in this answer.

You also mentioned it's been awhile since you've written recursive programs. This should get the wheels spinning again!

```js
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const concat = (xs, ...ys) =>
  ys.length === 0
    ? xs
    : xs.concat (concat (...ys))
  
const subsets = ([ x, ...xs ], _return = identity) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? _return ([ [ x ] ])
    : subsets 
        ( xs
        , ss =>
            _return ( concat ( [ [ x ] ]
                             , ss.map (s => concat ([ x ], s))
                             , ss
                             )
                    )
        )
        
for (const set of subsets ([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]))
  console.log (set)
```

The correct ordering is achieved

```
[ 1 ]
[ 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 1, 2, 4 ]
[ 1, 3 ]
[ 1, 3, 4 ]
[ 1, 4 ]
[ 2 ]
[ 2, 3 ]
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 2, 4 ]
[ 3 ]
[ 3, 4 ]
[ 4 ]
```

Related: [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) – while this program doesn't generate the correct ordering, it's simplified form shows you how you can begin to think about approaching the problem on your own. `concat` is now a basic binary operation and `powerSet` has simplified logic branches.

```js
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs.concat (ys)
  
const None =
  Symbol ()
  
const powerSet = ([ x = None, ...xs ], _return = identity) =>
  x === None
    ? _return ([ [] ]) // base case: no X
    : powerSet         // inductive case: at least one X
        ( xs
        , ss =>
            _return ( concat ( ss.map (s => concat ([ x ], s))
                             , ss
                             )
                    )
        )
          
console.log (powerSet ([ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]))
// [ [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
// , [ 'x', 'y' ]
// , [ 'x', 'z' ]
// , [ 'x' ]
// , [ 'y', 'z' ]
// , [ 'y' ]
// , [ 'z' ]
// , []
// ]
```

Despite being less complex, `powerSet` even works with an empty input, making it a [total function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function)

```
getCombinations ([])
// => undefined

subsets ([])
// => [ [ undefined ] ]

powerSet ([])
// => [ [] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparison function like this:

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12],
];

function sortNumericArrays(a, b){
    var i, l = a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length, result = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if(undefined === a[i]){
            result = -1;
            i = l;
        }else if(undefined === b[i]){
            result = 1;
            i = l;
        }else if(a[i] !== b[i]){
            result = a[i] - b[i];
            i = l;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(arr.sort(sortNumericArrays));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can mimic this, by using a natural sort by joining the number values by dots, or any other character you like.

```js
var list = [
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 4 ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 4 ],
  [ 1, 3 ],
  [ 1, 4 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 2, 3 ],
  [ 2, 4 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 3, 4 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 4 ]
];

function versionNumberSort(a, b) {
  return a.join('.').localeCompare(b.join('.'))
}

console.log(list.sort(versionNumberSort).map(l => l.join(', ')).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Here is a shorthand method, using floating-point sorting.

**Note:** This is a trick, and you could get floating-point precision errors with larger lists.

```js
var list = [
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 4 ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 4 ],
  [ 1, 3 ],
  [ 1, 4 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 2, 3 ],
  [ 2, 4 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 3, 4 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 4 ]
];

function sortNumberArrays(a, b) {
  return parseFloat('0.' + a.join('')) - parseFloat('0.' + b.join(''));
}

console.log(list.sort(sortNumberArrays).map(l => l.join(', ')).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<!--
Desired result:

[
  [ 1 ]
  [ 1, 2 ]
  [ 1, 2, 3]
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  [ 1, 2, 4]
  [ 1, 3 ]
  [ 1, 3, 4 ]
  [ 1, 4 ]
  [ 2 ]
  ...
  [ 4 ]
]
-->
```

Comment: @Birrel AFter failing to get the recursion to work, because you have too look at every element in each array when comparing, I utilized a simpler method. You can use natural sorting. Think of it as sorting version numbers or sections of an article.